# Error in ASP.NET controller while writing to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

Tell me why I get such an error when using the db.Test.Add (view) method;
Error: CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'DC.Models.View' to 'DC.Models.SaveComments.Test'. 
I try to write data to the database, code:

My Controller:

```
namespace DC.Controllers
{
    public class CommentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SaveRecord(View model)
        {
            try
            {
                DataComment db = new DataComment();
                View view = new View();
                view.Id = model.Id;
                view.Name = model.Name;

                db.Test.Add(view);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Models:

```
    namespace DC.Models.SaveComments
    {
        public class DataComment : DbContext
        {
            public DataComment()
                : base ("CC")
            { }
            public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
        }
    }

namespace DC.Models.SaveComments
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace DC.Models
{
    public class View
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And in html-page:

```
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRecord", "Comment", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <p>Id @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)</p>
    <p>Name @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-block btn-primary" />
    }
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You made the object of View It should be of test:**

```
namespace DC.Controllers
{
    public class CommentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SaveRecord(View model)
        {
            try
            {
                DataComment db = new DataComment();
                Test view= new Test(); //This is change
                view.Id = model.Id;
                view.Name = model.Name;

                db.Test.Add(view);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

**One more thing their is difference in model namespace please look at that also**

Or you can use like below:

```
public ActionResult SaveRecord(Test model)
        {
            try
            {
                DataComment db = new DataComment();

                db.Test.Add(model);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```